# Test if a variable is a list or tuple

Tags: python, types, list

In python, what's the best way to test if a variable contains a list or a tuple? (ie. a collection)

Is `isinstance()` as evil as suggested here? http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/

Update: the most common reason I want to distinguish a list from a string is when I have some indefinitely deep nested tree / data-structure of lists of lists of lists of strings etc. which I'm exploring with a recursive algorithm and I need to know when I've hit the "leaf" nodes.

Comment: Broadly dismissing type-checking as evil is a bit facile. It's part of the language. If it is so evil, someone should write a PEP to remove it.

Comment: What do you want to have as your behavior if you get some other kind of iterable collection (like a set or a string, for instance)?

Comment: @Adam Crossland: "It's part of the language." Just like division by zero.  It's avoidable.  In this case, without additional information, it's probably completely needless.  Most type checking in Python is needless.  Since not *all* is needless, some type checking needs to be present.  But that doesn't mean it's helpful, valuable, or even a good idea.

Comment: So you're saying that some type checking is needed, but despite that, it's useless, worthless and a bad idea.  Sorry, that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: The "XXX is evil" is badly-conceived, misleading shorthand for "the way you're asking to do XXX suggests you don't understand when it should actually be used, and you almost certainly want something else".  That's most likely the case here.

Comment: I didn't broadly dismiss it as evil. I wrote a short essay about when it's evil and when it's justifiable. That essay may be many things — right, wrong, clear, vague, enjoyable, boring — but one thing it is not is a broad dismissal of the technique.

Comment: Please do note that since PEP 3119 isinstance has become more correct. Thanks to the Abstract Base Classes isinstance is now the most correct way to decide fail-fast whether a class will support things like general collection protocols!

Comment: Also, oftentimes it is better to have fail-fast for things such as deferred method calls; it becomes very hard to debug why a deferred method call fails later on. In python 3 there is no "callable(x)"; the correct way to check if a given object is callable without calling it is to do isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Callable)

Comment: As I have explained in one of the answer's comment, sometimes it is necessary to know for sure some container is ordered, and this may only be possible by type checking (or may be in some cases, `getattr(obj, '__getitem__')`, but this is ugly). When the ordering of the elements in a container object does matter, an algorithm that does not check for this could potentially generate different results on different runs! I don't believe type-checking to be evil, because it could be essential.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Go ahead and use `isinstance` if you need it.  It is somewhat evil, as it excludes custom sequences, iterators, and other things that you might actually need.  However, sometimes you need to behave differently if someone, for instance, passes a string.  My preference there would be to explicitly check for `str` or `unicode` like so:

```
import types
isinstance(var, types.StringTypes)
```

N.B. Don't mistake `types.StringType` for `types.StringTypes`.  The latter incorporates `str` and `unicode` objects.

The `types` module is considered by many to be obsolete in favor of just checking directly against the object's type, so if you'd rather not use the above, you can alternatively check explicitly against `str` and `unicode`, like this:

```
isinstance(var, (str, unicode)):
```

**Edit:**

Better still is:

```
isinstance(var, basestring)
```

**End edit**

After either of these, you can fall back to behaving as if you're getting a normal sequence, letting non-sequences raise appropriate exceptions.

See the thing that's "evil" about type checking is not that you might want to behave differently for a certain type of object, it's that you artificially restrict your function from doing the right thing with unexpected object types that would otherwise do the right thing.  If you have a final fallback that is not type-checked, you remove this restriction.  It should be noted that too much type checking is a code smell that indicates that you might want to do some refactoring, but that doesn't necessarily mean you should avoid it from the getgo.

Comment: The types module is a bit of a historical artifact. As mentioned on http://docs.python.org/dev/library/types.html#module-types if you really must check for the `str` type you should just use that directly, instead of using `types.StringType` which is just an alias for it.

But I do not think this answer answers the question as asked, because that was about "a collection". Unless you're using a python new enough to have the `abc` module that's not something you can use `isinstance` to check for, and even then I would recommend avoiding the check if at all possible.

Comment: `assert isinstance(u'abc', str) == False`.  I agree that it is better to check against the type directly, rather than using the `types` module, but `types.StringTypes` does something that `str` doesn't: it returns True for `str` and `unicode` objects.  I'll edit my response to offer a double check as an alternative.

Comment: I realize I didn't answer the question of checking for collections directly, but the actual question asked was "Is `isinstance` evil?"  And I gave a counter example which (1) is a non-evil use of `isinstance`, because having a fallback means it doesn't break ducktyping, and (2) is a good solution for a very common motivation people have for wanting to check if something is a `list` or `tuple` (i.e. to disambiguate them from strings).

Comment: I agree, with the caveat that often it's useful for custom types to behave like strings, too. But Python's OO only goes so far...

Comment: Does `class Foo(str): pass` do what you want?

Comment: Alas, this does not work on python 3.2, as types module does not contain StringType or StringTypes at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's why I offer the other version, which in python 3 would translate to `isinstance(foo, (str, bytes))`.

Comment: Anyway, your suggestion is good. However I detest that when I am creating methods that need to accept single objects or composite collections and act as if the former were a collection of 1, always having to check separately if my "collection" happens to be a str, unicode or bytes. Not a nice feature from python - "string as a immutable collection of characters" is just not so useful as BDFL might have imagined in the first place ;)

Answer (score 662):

```
if type(x) is list:
    print 'a list'
elif type(x) is tuple:
    print 'a tuple'
else:
    print 'neither a tuple or a list'
```

Comment: Does not seem to work :  type([]) ==> list;   type([]) is list ===> False

Comment: In Python 2.7.5: `type([]) is list` returns `True`

Comment: `type(x) in [list,tuple]` is shorter.

Comment: if x and type(x) is list: to avoid the [] mismatch

Answer (score 43):

There's nothing wrong with using `isinstance` as long as it's not redundant. If a variable should only be a list/tuple then document the interface and just use it as such. Otherwise a check is perfectly reasonable:

```
if isinstance(a, collections.abc.Iterable):
    # use as a container
else:
    # not a container!
```

This type of check does have some good use-cases, such as with the standard string [startswith](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) / [endswith](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) methods (although to be accurate these are implemented in C in CPython using an explicit check to see if it's a tuple - there's more than one way to solve this problem, as mentioned in the article you link to).

An explicit check is often better than trying to use the object as a container and handling the exception - that can cause all sorts of problems with code being run partially or unnecessarily.

Comment: This is a nice way to check if a variable is iterable.  However, it probably won't work for the purposes of this question.  Be advised that a string is iterable too and would probably create a false positive.

Comment: A `set` object is also an iterable, which means that while you can surely pop elements from it, but it does not guarantee a certain order, which is a very dangerous thing for certain algorithms. In the cases when ordering of the elements does matter, an algorithm using this snippet could potentially generate different results on different runs!

Comment: Looks like for 2.x, it was available under [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable), but it's been moved to the abstract base class (abc), so now it's called [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable)

Answer (score 11):

Document the argument as needing to be a sequence, and use it as a sequence. Don't check the type.

Answer (score 11):

On Python 2.8 `type(list) is list` returns `false`  
I would suggest comparing the type in this horrible way:

```
if type(a) == type([]) :
  print "variable a is a list"
```

(well at least on my system, using anaconda on Mac OS X Yosemite)

Comment: Does type(a) is list also evaluates to false ?

Comment: Did you mean Python 2.7.8?  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/#official-pronouncement

Comment: Hello, I'm curious: Why do you consider your example "horrible"?

Comment: `type(list) is list` returns `False` because `type(list)` is `type`, not `list`.  `type(list()) is list` or with any other *instance* of a list will return `True`.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend the only pythonic way:

```py
if isinstance(x, (list, tuple))): pass
```

Comment: 13 years after the original question was published, this answer is the most straightforward way to accomplish this in Python3.

Comment: This alternative works with a `tuple` of types, not with a `list` of them.

Comment: Works also for `dict`. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.__class__.__name__ in ('list', 'tuple')
True
```

Answer (score 9):

How about: `hasattr(a, "__iter__")` ?

It tells if the object returned can be iterated over as a generator.  By default, tuples and lists can, but not the string types.

Comment: Also results True for strings (at least on Python 3).

Comment: This is wrong answer. Since type 'str' has the method '__iter__' also. @SzieberthAdam was right. The type 'set' also is iterable, but is not orderable.

Comment: Also dicts have ``__iter__``.

Comment: If you continue, any custom type may have `__iter__` for some reason...

Answer (score 8):

Python uses "Duck typing", i.e. if a variable kwaks like a duck, it must be a duck. In your case, you probably want it to be iterable, or you want to access the item at a certain index. You should just do this: i.e. use the object in `for var:` or `var[idx]` inside a `try` block, and if you get an exception it wasn't a duck...

Comment: The problem with this is if `var` is a string iteration will occur with probably unexpected results.

Comment: Despite the fact stated by Brian M. Hunt, his is quite a pythonic solution, in terms of asking for forgiveness rather than permission.

Answer (score 5):

Another easy way to find out if a variable is either list or tuple or generally check variable type would be :

```py
def islist(obj):
    if ("list" in str(type(obj))):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to know if you can use the `foo[123]` notation with the variable, you can check for the existence of a `__getitem__` attribute (which is what python calls when you access by index) with `hasattr(foo, '__getitem__')`

Answer (score 3):

Has to be more complex test if you really want to handle just about anything as function argument.

```
type(a) != type('') and hasattr(a, "__iter__")
```

Although, usually it's enough to just spell out that a function expects iterable  and then check only `type(a) != type('')`.

Also it may happen that for a string you have a simple processing path or you are going to be nice and do a split etc., so you don't want to yell at strings and if someone sends you something weird, just let him have an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, I agree with Ignacio, above, but you can also use *type* to check if something is a tuple or a list.

```
>>> a = (1,)
>>> type(a)
(type 'tuple')
>>> a = [1]
>>> type(a)
(type 'list')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `isinstance` with `typing`.

```
from typing import List, Tuple
>> isinstance([1,2], Tuple)
False
>> isinstance([1,2], List)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but I do (for Python 3):

```
if hasattr(instance, '__iter__') and not isinstance(instance, (str, bytes)):
    ...
```

This allows other iterables (like Django querysets) but excludes strings and bytestrings.  I typically use this in functions that accept either a single object ID or a list of object IDs.  Sometimes the object IDs can be strings and I don't want to iterate over those character by character. :)

Answer (score 0):

You know... I may be doing this the stupid way, but I do this:

```
try:
    len(thing)
except:
    # not a list
```

Like, if I can know the length of it, it gotta be more than one thing.

Edit: Just realized it won't work if the non-list item is a string (since a string is essentially a list of characters).

Comment: The typechecker may get a bit mad with this, though.

Comment: That's not going to separate a list or other collection from a string, though. Strings support len()

Comment: Just realized it. Works nice for numbers and such, though.