# How to check if an element of a list is a list (in Python)?

Tags: python

If we have the following list:

```
list = ['UMM', 'Uma', ['Ulaster','Ulter']]
```

If I need to find out if an element in the list is itself a list, what can I replace *aValidList* in the following code with?

```
for e in list:
    if e == aValidList:
        return True
```

Is there a special import to use?  Is there a best way of checking if a variable/element is a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if a variable is a list or tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184955/test-if-a-variable-is-a-list-or-tuple)

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you trying to flatten your list?

Comment: Also: *(1)* Don't use `list` as variable name because it will shadow the built-in `list()`. *(2)* What should be the meaning of those round brackets?

Comment: @RikPoggi It's an exercise I'm trying.  Originally we were asked to go through a standard list and return the count of elements which started with a capital "U".  I wanted to see if I could expand it to search both the list and a sub-list for the same and return the count.  So the procedure would return a count of four if the above list was the input.  The () were typos. :-)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(e, list):
```

If you want to check that an object is a list or a tuple, pass several classes to `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
```

Answer (score 23):

1. Work out what specific properties of a `list` you want the items to have. Do they need to be indexable? Sliceable? Do they need an `.append()` method?
2. Look up the abstract base class which describes that particular type in the [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module.
3. Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance):

   ```
   isinstance(x, collections.MutableSequence)
   ```

---

You might ask "why not just use `type(x) == list`?" You shouldn't do that, because then you won't support things that look like lists. And part of the Python mentality is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

> I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck

In other words, you shouldn't require that the objects are `list`s, just that they have the methods you will need. The `collections` module provides a bunch of abstract base classes, which are a bit like Java interfaces. Any type that is an instance of `collections.Sequence`, for example, will support indexing.

Comment: Abstract Baseclass reference (`collections.MutableSequence` is correct for `list`, but here is the main reference), for others who are reading this answer and curious: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes

Comment: @ninjagecko yep that's the link in #2 =)

Comment: @Alex your advice is technically correct, but it requires extra work that is not usually necessary. Why not just use `isinstance(x, list)`? It is straightforward, standard practice, and considered good practice. Plus, thinking about interfaces and ABCs is likely to stump a beginner programmer. A "better" solution is not best practice if it is too much trouble to use consistently.

Comment: @alexis `isinstance(x, list)` is not considered good practice, at least not in my books! It's OK if you're sure that you're never going to see any custom objects, but how much harder is it to do `isinstance(x, collections.MutableSequence)`?

Comment: Well your authors probably know best, so I won't defend my point. But I've just been looking on the [python FAQ][1]  and it just advises using `isinstance` with a class, or better yet avoiding it altogether.

Comment: Forgot the link: [1]: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-given-class-or-of-a-subclass-of-it

Answer (score 11):

Expression you are looking for may be:

```
...
return any( isinstance(e, list) for e in my_list )
```

Testing:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2]
>>> any( isinstance(e, list) for e in my_list )
False
>>> my_list = [1,2, [3,4,5]]
>>> any( isinstance(e, list) for e in my_list )
True
>>>
```

Comment: It's probably worth stressing that the variable named `list` in the question will hide the `list` type, meaning that most of the other answers posted here will fail if simply pasted in. (It's embarrassing how often I've been bitten by that one.)

Comment: +1 for using `any()` instead of some for-loop-if combination.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, more intuitive way would be like this

```
if type(e) is list:
    print('Found a list element inside the list')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write:

```
for item,i in zip(your_list, range(len(your_list)):

    if type(item) == list:
        print(f"{item} at index {i} is a list")
```