# Check for nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I was wondering whether it is possible to check for the existence of nested lists in Python. As in, is there a built in module/function that could allow to check for a nested list item or the index at which such a list may be found?

```
def func(list_name):
    #check for nested list
```

The function here and my basic presumption for this scenario is that I'm not aware of the list passed on to the function by the user. Given this, I'm trying to see whether `list_name` has any nested lists within it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because shows minimal effort to solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759930/how-to-check-if-an-element-of-a-list-is-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
def func(list_name):
    for i in list_name:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1, 2, "asdf", [1, 2, 3], {"q": 1}]
    func(a)
```