# How do I create a list with one item per index from a list with multiple items per index

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, indexing, iteration

I am trying to use XlsxWriter to generate a spreadsheet. I am able to create a list of lists to iterate through for the spreadsheet but some index positions are currently lists as well.

Here is my list of lists:

```
listOfLists = [
    ['sg-1111111111111111', 'launch-wizard-1', [80, 22], ['0.0.0.0/0', '0.0.0.0/0'], ['All'], ['0.0.0.0/0'], 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['sg-2222222222222222', 'ASG-SG', [22], ['0.0.0.0/0'], ['All'], ['0.0.0.0/0'], 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['sg-3333333333333333', 'WebSecGrp', [80], ['0.0.0.0/0'], ['All'], ['0.0.0.0/0'], 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['sg-4444444444444444', 'WebDMZSG', [80, 22, 443], ['0.0.0.0/0', '0.0.0.0/0', '0.0.0.0/0'], ['All'], ['0.0.0.0/0'], 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['sg-5555555555555555', 'default', ['All'], ['All'], ['All'], ['0.0.0.0/0'], 'vpc-033da694c7bd5e1b9'],
    ['sg-6666666666666666', 'launch-wizard-2', [22], ['0.0.0.0/0'], ['All'], ['0.0.0.0/0'], 'vpc-11346c6b']
]
```

I want to move through each list and create a new list with one item per index position. The solution should move through each list until there are no more items in the list. On secondary passes through the list, if an index position is empty, the corresponding position in the new list should be empty as well. Iteration through each list should continue until there are no more items in any of the index positions of that particular list. The end result should be:

```
newListofLists = [
    ['sg-1111111111111111', 'launch-wizard-1', '80', '0.0.0.0/0', 'All', '0.0.0.0/0', 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['', '', '22', '0.0.0.0/0', '', '', ''],
    ['sg-2222222222222222', 'ASG-SG', '22', '0.0.0.0/0', 'All', '0.0.0.0/0', 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['sg-3333333333333333', 'WebSecGrp', '80', '0.0.0.0/0', 'All', '0.0.0.0/0', 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['sg-4444444444444444', 'WebDMZSG', '80', '0.0.0.0/0', 'All', '0.0.0.0/0', 'vpc-11346c6b'],
    ['', '', '22', '0.0.0.0/0', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '443', '0.0.0.0/0', '', '', ''],
    ['sg-5555555555555555', 'default', 'All', 'All', 'All', '0.0.0.0/0', 'vpc-033da694c7bd5e1b9'],
    ['sg-6666666666666666', 'launch-wizard-2', '22', '0.0.0.0/0', 'All', '0.0.0.0/0', 'vpc-11346c6b']
]
```

Thank you in advance Hive mind! :)

Comment: What was stopping you from writing the code which does that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't know how. I have tried but my Python skills are very limited, hence reaching out here for help.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, so this is off-topic.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this: As you work through the line, start with an empty list of lists and a couple counter integers: How many secondary lists are in use, how far down this list am I?  Move primary items to the first list.  If I see the need to move an item to a secondary list, and there is no such list (var 1 too low) then make a list of blanks up to this point (var 2 - 1) and move the item to the new list, put it in the list of lists.  Now, every item you go through, you need to either move values or blanks to every active secondary list.  At the end of the line, put your lists into the newListofLists.

Refining the idea, the empty list of lists could be the end of the newListofLists, where you keep a variable of the base (primary) list position.  Complexity metrics may not like it!  Going back and playing catch up is brutally complex, so:

Further revision for simplicity: for every line, prescan to find out how many lists it will generate, and on the second pass, fill that many lists with values or blanks.  Now you just need an output base position variable, a lists count variable and a list iterator variable.

Of course, my python is so weak I do not know how to tell if a list item is a list!  But Google and Stack Overflow are my friends: [How to check if an element of a list is a list (in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759930/how-to-check-if-an-element-of-a-list-is-a-list-in-python)  This is just high level input-output analysis!  Lots left for you!