# Python: Get item(s) at index list

Tags: python

I am trying to write something that takes a list, and gets the item(s) at an index, either one or multiple.

The example below which I found in another post here works great when I have more than one index. This example doesnt work if b = a single index.

```
a = [-2,1,5,3,8,5,6]
b = [1,2,5] 
c = [ a[i] for i in b]
```

How do I get this to work with both 1 and multiple index?
Example:

```
a = [-2,1,5,3,8,5,6]
b = 2 
c = [ a[i] for i in b] doesnt work in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually check if the type your trying to use for fetching the indices is a list (or a tuple, etc.). Here it is, wrapped into a function:

```
def find_values(in_list, ind):
    # ind is a list of numbers
    if isinstance(ind, list):
        return [in_list[i] for i in ind]
    else:
        # ind is a single numer
        return [in_list[ind]]

in_list = [-2,1,5,3,8,5,6]
list_of_indices = [1,2,5]
one_index = 3

print(find_values(in_list, list_of_indices))
print(find_values(in_list, one_index))
```

The function takes the input list and the indices (renamed for clarity - it's best to avoid single letter names). The indices can either be a list or a single number. If `isinstance` determines your input is a list, it proceeds with a list comprehension. If it's a number - it just treats it as an index. If it is anything else, the program crashes.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759930/how-to-check-if-an-element-of-a-list-is-a-list-in-python) gives you more details on `isinstance` and recognizing other iterables, like tuples, or lists and tuples together.

Comment: Wow that's very helpful and thorough!
Thank you very much, I'm going to try this out tomorrow!

Comment: Gladly! Many (most?) languages have some ways to determine a type, inheritance, properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list that manually validates the value of list b in the list a, you could create a separate 3 line code to print out the overlapping intersection of list a and b by this:

```
a = [-2,1,5,3,8,5,6]
b = [3,4,6] 

for i in range(0,len(b)):
    if b[i] in a:
        print(b[i])
```

By doing so, you would be able to print out the overlapping intersection even if there were 1 or even no value stored in list b.

Comment: OP asks what he or she should do if the b is not iterable but simply one indice. So you are not answering really the need.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [-2, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5, 6]
a2 = [-2]
b = [1, 2, 5]
b2 = [1]
c = [a[i] for i in b]
c2 = [a2[i-1] for i in b2]
```

The first item of the list is 0, the list with one item is perfectly valid.