# Union type passed as the only argument to isinstance() in Python

Tags: python, types

Consider I want to check whether a variable `var` is an instance of either type `A` or type `B`. There's the canonical way to do so, discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184955):

```py
result: bool = isinstance(var, (A, B))
```

The following appears to work just as well, however (see [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/)):

```py
result: bool = isinstance(var, A | B)
```

The question is: are the above two code fragments equivalent?

Comment: Going with *The new syntax should be accepted for calls to isinstance and issubclass as long as the Union items are valid arguments to isinstance and issubclass themselves.* I would say yes, they are equivalent

Comment: @python_user Thank you! Could you convert your comment into an answer to be up-voted an accepted?